# Order e-mail by size

Tags: ios

Is it possible to sort iOS Mail.app by size? How can this be done, because it's default ordered by sent date.
I'd like to remove the biggest mails from my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Mail does not sort messages by anything but date.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this free app from iTunes store.

> [search mail by size By iNobilis ltd](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/search-mail-by-size/id388632871?mt=8).
>
> Find big emails in your Gmail to get your space back!
>
> search mail by size allows find big mails, sorting and filtering mail
>   by the size of email attachments (largest to smallest) and allows
>   sending selected email messages to the GMail web trash folder. The
>   application can sort thousands of email messages in just a few
>   seconds.

Disclaimer: Have not tried it my self.

Comment: What about all except gmail? (:

Comment: so what email provider do you have

Comment: One gmail, 2x Outlook, 2x custom domain and office 365